# Integral inequality problem (cauchy-schwarz)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that any continuously differentiable function $f : [a,b] \rightarrow R$ for which $f(a) = 0$ satisfies the following inequality $$\int^b_a f(x)^2dx \leqslant (b-a)^2 \int_a^b f^{'}(x)^2dx$$
By looking at it, I think we need to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I am unable to go any further. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus $$f(x) = \int^x_a f^{'}(t)dt$$ Square both sides and use the cauchy-schwarz inequality, $$f(x)^2 = \left(\int_a^bf^{'}(t)dt\right)^2 \leqslant (b-a)\int^x_a f^{'}(t)^2dt$$
The R.H.S. is a constant and the L.H.S depends on x. Integrate the inequality w.r.t. x gives us $$\int^b_a f(x)^2 dx \leqslant (b-a)^2 \int_a^b f^{'}(t)^2dt$$ which is your problem statement.